# How to link DataCardValue to another view

Tags: sharepoint, office365, powerapps

I have a screen where a user can edit a form, the form is pulling from a sharepoint list.  I would like to link the value of a lookup field from this form to a new view pulling from a **different** sharepoint list.

[image]

Ideally the value **Vendor 1** would link to a DetailsScreen for the specific vendor.  The issue is I am unable to add the necessary **OnSelect** function to the **DataCard** to achieve this and even the default **Navigate** Function does nothing when attached to the **DataCardValue**. The default Navigate function does work in other elements, for example in the **arrow** to the right of Vendor 1, which I added as a test.  I attempted the solution [here](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-PowerApps-Formerly/Creating-link-from-one-view-to-another-view/td-p/34514), but was unsuccessful. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried with Textbox, Dropdownbox and combobox and for all of them onselect worked fine for me

```
Navigate(Screen2,ScreenTransition.None,{ FirstName: "CRM365" , Argument2: "SomeText" })
```

I would say simple try using arrow button and try navigating and then go step by step

[image]